# Excel delete all values in one column that are different to another column

Tags: excel

I have data with each row being each participant and I want to delete rows (participants) that do not have a certain value from one column (image 4, code 1 title in column A) that is the same as in another column from a different spreadsheet (image 5, column A). The problem with just copying and pasting the numbers from column A in image 5 to column A in image 4 is that the numbers in column A of image 4 must match up with the rows (participants) in image four.

Image 4 - data

[image]

Image 5 - values of image 4, column A that I want to keep

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a vlookup to check if the current code 1 exist in image 5
in cell f3 on the fisrt sheet paste:

```
vlookup(a3,Sheet2!$a$2:$a$19,1,0)
```

That will check if the value exist if not it will show NA
Note that I assumed that your 2nd sheet is named sheet2... if not change the name to current.
after that use the filter (date->filter) to exclude all the na's